# Xlsx Writer Conditional Formatting Based on Other Cell

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

Given this format and conditional formatting:

```
# Add a format. Light red fill.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE'})
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B14', 
{'type':'cell', 
'criteria': '<', 
'value': 1, 
'format': format1
})
```

I'd like to apply this criteria to cells B2:B14 if corresponding cells C2:C14 meet the criteria. For example, if cell C2 is less than 1, then apply the format to cell B2.

@jmcnamara ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first step would be to figure out how to do that in Excel and then apply that to the XlsxWriter code in your program.

Comment: @jmcnamara - In Excel's conditional formatting dialogue  box (Conditional Formatting - New Rule), it allows one to specify the reference cells by selecting "use a formula to determine which cells to format". Because the cells to format are already selected, the rule just applies to those cells. I don't think XLSX writer has such an option. No?

Comment: Yes. XlsxWriter has a `formula` type in `conditional_format` that represents that. From your answer below it looks like you found that already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This worked:

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE'})
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B14', 
{'type':'formula', 
'criteria': '=$C2<10',  
'format': format1
})
```

Comment: The part I was missing was to use a relative reference to the start of the range, even though the documentation says to use absolute references.